# How to create/modify kendo dropdown into a nested dropdown?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I want to create a **nested dropdown** which both of them have external datasource?

Example of which i wanted to achieve is just like this,

```
1. Plane
2. Ship
3. Car -> Car Brand A 
       -> Car Brand B 
       -> Car Brand C
```

(Plane,Ship,Car) From Transport Datasource and (Car Brand A,B,C) From Car Brand Datasource, do anyone have any idea how this can be achieved in kendo way, because i haven't found one yet

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you:

[Cascading drop down list](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist)

It is relatively simple to implement and should give you the ability to change your second datasource based on the first selected datasource.

Comment: not really what i looking for, i'm looking how to create/modify the template they provide in one of their example page but what they create using that editable template is only a simple modified header,value,selectedvalue

Comment: If you can either create or provide an example image of what it is you are trying to achieve I should be able to provide you a code example.